# Css selector with class selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm using the following selector to style an element whihc is on the first child of the parent element I select! since the element doesn't have a specific class I use this method. But the style doesn't get added to the element.

```
.order-bar div[class^='col-']:first-child i[class^='fa-']:before{
    padding: 0px 20px;
    color: #ccc !important;
}
```

html

```
<div class='order-bar'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <!-- other elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[class^='fa-']` part is the problem. The class attribute of the `i` element doesn't start with `fa-`. Change it to `fa` or use `i.fa:before` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! :) so one questions regarding the selector I wrote. the class part should contain the starting class pattern. As in if the class attrib containes `class='fa fa-icon'` my selector should start with `[class^='fa']`

Comment: You also need something for the content property in :before to see anything.

Comment: @WillReese Yeah there is! Thanks for the headsup but I haven't included the entire css here! :)

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri Yes, but since you can use `.fa` there is no need to use _attribute starts with_ selector in this case.